# Nodejs - Why my next function is called so many times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm uploading a file using a POST method and i want to do something after the upload, but the next function is called so many times.
What am i doing wrong?

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){
    //console.log('upload');
    var fileName = req.headers['filename'];
    var destinationFile = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/upload/'+ fileName);
    var pipe = req.pipe(destinationFile);

    req.on('end', function(){
    res.sendStatus(200);
        next();
  });


},function(req, res){
    console.log('do something..');
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you call `next()` at all, it moves to the next matching route? If you want to do something after the file has uploaded, do it in the route you're currently in, there's no need to call `next()`

Comment: @adeneo So, i want to move or delete the uploaded file, Whats the best way to do that?If i remove the next call the log doesn't appear on the console. Thank you for the support

Comment: http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

Comment: @adeneo Thank you i did it following the link.